# How to send a file from REST API to front-end?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, rest, filestream

I am trying to write a service which builds an .ics calendar file from string (which works) and send it to front-end. Front-end gets that file as a result of an api query. This is how it looks on my side:

```
var dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(icsString);
var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StreamContent(dataStream) };
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "file.ics" };
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return httpResponseMessage;
```

Is it correct? If it should work, then how to get the data in JS on the front-end side?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, you need to close the `fileStream` and set `responseStream` Position to 0. You can refer to my code. and please make sure that file is present at the path and you are handling the exception

```
      //Copy the source file stream to MemoryStream and close the file stream
      MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream();
      Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Open);

      fileStream.CopyTo(responseStream);
      fileStream.Close();
      responseStream.Position = 0;

      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
      response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

      //Write the memory stream to HttpResponseMessage content
      response.Content = new StreamContent(responseStream);
      string contentDisposition = string.Concat("attachment; filename=", fileName);
      response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
                    ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition);
      return response;
```

Comment: Actually, I don't use FileStream - I want to send a string as a file. So what I do is create ByteArray from string and put it to MemoryStream. I positioned MemoryStream to 0 but it didn't help. HttpResponseMessage at the end has length like 324. Does it mean it is attached correctly and the front-end part is just reading it wrong?